# No eigenvalues for ODE in semi-infinite domain?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I cannot understand the existence of eigenvalues of ODE regarding semi-infinite domain. Before post the question, what I've already known is as follows.

Given a linear 1D wave equation as follows

$$
\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}} = \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}
$$

Find solutions of such form,

$$
u = f(x) e^{i \omega t}
$$

Obviously, original equation can be reduced to be

$$
\omega^{2} f + f^{''} = 0
$$

The characteristic polynomial of this ODE is

$$
\omega^{2} + \lambda^{2} = 0
$$

So, we get $\lambda = \pm i \omega$. Then, the general solution is

$$
f(x) = A e^{i \omega x} + B e^{-i \omega x}
$$

Impose boundary condition of the following form,

$$
\begin{align}
u(x = 0, t) &= 0 \\
u(x = 1, t) &= 0
\end{align}
$$

Then we get discrete eigenvalues $\omega_{n}=n \pi, n=0,1,2,3,...$, since the trivial solution of $A=B=0$ is discarded.

Now, **the problem comes.**

If impose the boundary condition as follows,

$$
\begin{align}
u(x=0,t)=0 \\
u(x\rightarrow \infty, t) \rightarrow 0
\end{align}
$$

Thanks!
is there any eigenvalues? How could I deal with the infinite domain?

---

OK. If we can say there are no eigenvalues because the sum of a cosine and sine is not well defined when it approaches $\infty$. Then there are statements in a textbook, [Stability and transition in shear flows](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387989853) as follows,

> If, on the other hand, the boundary condition at infinity is relaxed to $u(x,t)$ is bounded as $x \rightarrow \infty$, we obtain a continuous spectrum $\omega \geq 0$.

So, why the condition of boundedness leads to the existence of eigenvalues?

Answer (score 0):

The complex conjugate eigenvalues, with zero real part, of $f(x)$ imply that the solution can also be written as the sum of a cosine and sine, multiplied by some constants.

However the limit of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ is not well defined, so one could argue that the only well defined solution would be setting the constants to zero in order to satisfy the boundary conditions.